# Store timestamp the RIGHT way

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timestamp

I use UNIX TIMESTAMPS for everything and the thought of year 2038 is creeping the heck out of me. Anyway, I've been storing timestamps as int(10) since when I can remember because when I tried to struggle with the TIMESTAMP data type it kept adding "CURRENT TIMESTAMP" to the field and I didn't want that. So my question is what is the correct way of storing a timestamp? ( and not having it updated every time the record is updated )

In addition, having in mind that year 2038 is soon to come and hopefully we'll all be alive then, what is the best substitute for timestamps?

In one more addition, what is going to happen with strtotime when timestamps go extinct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way i can think of is using `DateTime` column type. When retrieving the date and if you need timestamp simply use PHP `strtotime($row['Date_Column']);` that will get you the timestamp.

Note that DateTime type records in the following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Also note that if your application is used in different timezones you would need to handle it on PHP side have some kind of wrap around function like:

```
function dateTimezone($ts, $format) {
   $timezone = YOUR TIME ZONE

   $d = new \DateTime();
   $d->setTimestamp($ts);
   $d->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));

   return $d->format($format);
}
```

will return date in the timezone that your user is, simply pass another parameter User ID or User Name and based on user choose the timezone variable.

And then instead of using php date function use the following: `dateTimezone(strtotime($row['MYSQL_DATE_COLUMN']), 'm/d/Y h:ia');`

Comment: "will get you the correct timestamp" is at best highly optimistic. Assuming that the times stored are UTC (the only sane approach if you go international) and that the PHP default timezone is not UTC (practically certain) this will produce wrong results. If the stored times are *not* UTC, there is the additional bonus of ambiguous times around daylight savings change boundaries.

Comment: well yea the question didnt mention anything regarding timezones. Timezones are different and more complicated that it seems.

Comment: Timezones are not "different", they are an integral part of a date/time value. "12:00 today" is not good enough -- do you mean in Tokyo, here, or in Buenos Aires?

Comment: but mysql has to hold only 1 timezone wherever server belongs and then PHP can handle the display of timezone. If he/she records time based on timezone in mysql he/she will have big problems when it comes to script execution such as cron

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that you cannot blindly `strtotime` anything and assume the result will be correct.

Comment: thats not what my answer implied. My answer simply answered his/her question. If there were timezones involved then wraparound function would be required and not just strtotime. Anyways updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a native mysql datetime field. It has a supported date range of

```
 1000-01-01 00:00:00 -> 9999-12-31 23:59:59
```

which should be enough for most any purposes. As you state, 32bit timestamps will wrap around in January 2038. While 64bit time_t is becoming more common place, it's not something you can rely on being available yet.

Answer (score 1):

### DATETIME:

```
min = 1000-01-01 00:00:00
max = 9999-12-31 23:59:59
size = 8bytes
```

### TIMESTAMP:

```
min = 1.1.1970 00:00:00
max = 2038-01-19 03:14:07
size = 4bytes
```

Note that TIMESTAMP supports timezones. Also inserts mysql into the first TIMESTAMP column of a row the current value of TIMESTAMP and will it automatically update if you don't use a specific value when updateing the row.

So I think you would like to use DATETIME.

Comment: I wonder what will happen in `9999-12-31 23:59:59` after 1 second :D

Comment: @GGio - If you're around to notice, please ring me up. :)